# to show a thumbnail of photo that I took-Phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a thumbnail of the photo that I take with the camera but I've failed, someone can give me an idea?

I'm working with PhoneGap, javascript, html and css

Comment: What did you do that failed?

Comment: [what-have-you-tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(imageURI){
            $('img').attr('src',imageURI).css({'background-size':  '100%', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'width': '100px'});
        },
        function(message) { alert('Get picture failed'); },
        { quality: 60, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true  }
        );
});
```

Comment: But if you have a big list of images will be slow because it resize the images, is not a thumbnail...