# Show recent captured image with Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to be able to show the recent captured image via the button `<button onclick="showImage();">Show Image</button><br>`, but not sure how to do this and I can't find any good information about it in the Phonegap API. Basically it's the function `showImage();` I need help creating.

The code for capturing an image is being executed correctly and I am running iOS 6.

Phonegap/Cordova:

```
  <title>Capture Image</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
                var i, path, len;
                for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                    readDataUrl = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

                }
            };

            function captureError(error) {
                var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
                document.getElementById('errormsg').innerHTML = msg;
            }

            function captureImage(){
                document.getElementById('format-data').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('capture-result').innerHTML = "";
                navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureImageSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
            }

            }

            function captureImageSuccess(mediaFiles) {
                var i, len;

                var formatSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
                    document.getElementById('format-data').innerHTML =
                    "Height: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].height + "</strong><br/>" +
                    "Width: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].width + "</strong><br/>";
                };
                for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                    // uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
                    document.getElementById('capture-result').innerHTML = "<br/><strong>" + (i+1) + " file<br/> Path: " + mediaFiles[i].fullPath + "</strong><br/>" +
                    "Height: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].height + "</strong><br/>" +
                    "Width: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].width + "</strong><br/>";
                    mediaFiles[i].getFormatData(formatSuccess, formatError);
                }
                console.log("captureImageSuccess");
            }


            </script>

    </head>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <button onclick="captureImage();">Capture Image</button> <br>
        <button onclick="showImage();">Show Image</button><br>
        <div class="result-block">
            Capture Result: <span id="capture-result"></span><br/>
            <span id="errormsg"></span>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have the image's full path, just create an `img` element :

```
<img id="picResult" />
```

and in your javascript set it's url whenever you get a response:

```
var formatSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
    document.getElementById('format-data').innerHTML =
    "Height: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].height + "</strong><br/>" +
    "Width: <strong>" + mediaFiles[i].width + "</strong><br/>";

    //HERE:
    document.getElementById('picResult').src = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted answer to issue similar like yours. That post show you how you show captured picture on a thumbnail.

See how you could solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043467/1853864

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img id="picResult" width="100px" border="1" />
```

JS

```
// capture callback
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
var i, path, len;
for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    // do something interesting with the file
$('#picResult').attr('src',path);
   }
};
```

- Make sure to check the PhoneGap version number on top right of these online docs to make sure you are doing things right.

**SEE HOW HERE TOO**  [PhoneGap - Media Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile)